# Build anchor tag with style attribute in XSL

Tags: xslt, styles, anchor

I have no formal training on XSL and am totally new to it. Basically I have a XML file as follows:

```
<document document="wpc_article_video_qp">
  <properties>
    <property type="name" prop_ns="http://sapportals.com/xmlns/cm" prop_name="displayname"/>
    <property type="createdBy">USER.PRIVATE_DATASOURCE.un:LU23921</property>
    <property type="includeInRSS" prop_ns="wpc_wcm" prop_name="wpc_wcm_rss"/>
    <property type="displayNewIcon" prop_ns="wpc_wcm" prop_name="wpc_wcm_new"/>
  </properties>
  <elements>
    <element type="videotitle">TestTitle</element>
    <element type="videopath">ICT/LB_1152kbps.mp4</element>
    <element type="videowidth">500</element>
    <element type="videoheight">250</element>
  </elements>
  <relatedlinks/>
  <relatedfiles/>
</document>
```

I have no control on the XML. What I mean is that the XML is generated by a tool and I cannot change it. What I am trying to do now is to write XSL which should generate a anchor tag as follows:

```
<a style="display:block;width:500px;height:250px" id="player" href="ICT/LB_1152kbps.mp4"></a>
```

where the href, width and height are picked up from "videopath", "videowidth" and "videoheight" XML elements respectively.

I tried to search on this website and some of the other websites but as I said since I am totally new to XSL, I don't really kwow where to begin. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a good place to begin, I'd recommend picking up an XSLT book in a library or so, or have a look at some online tutorial like [the one by Zvon](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/). When writing XSLT, I highly recommend a spezicalized editor lixe [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.). It not only saves you from typing a lot with its autocempletion features and by closing tags automatically, it also checks whether all the program code and XPath syntax are valid.

The question here is is: You probably generate a whole HTML document, not only a single anchor tag. So, here is a template that generates the anchor tag by matching the `<element>` element, but has to be integrated into a whole stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="element">
  <a style="display:block;
            width:{element/@videowidth}px;
            height:{element/@videoheight}px" 
     id="player" href="{element/@videopath}"></a>
</xsl:template>
```

**Edit:** If you really want an output document that just contains the anchor tag: The XSLT processor starts processing the input document at the root node and then steps through the elements as you tell it using `<xsl:apply-templates>` (or `<xsl:for-each>`). If you want that the template matching `<element>` to actually kick in, you have to "move" to that context from the document element context:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document/elements/element"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your response. I tried a very simple XSL as follows: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/><xsl:template match="element">
  <a style="display:block;
            width:{element/@videowidth}px;
            height:{element/@videoheight}px" 
     id="player" href="{element/@videopath}"></a>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet> however, the result is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to do this, using [AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) (Attribute Value Templates):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="elements">
     <xsl:copy>
       <a style="display:block;
                 width:{*[@type='videowidth']}px;
                 height:{*[@type='videoheight']}px"
                 id="player" href="{*[@type='videopath']}"></a>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**:

The CSS properties above are on a new line each -- this is done for readability. In a real transformation one may want to keep them without intervening space -- to produce the wanted result without spaces.

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<document document="wpc_article_video_qp">
  <properties>
    <property type="name" prop_ns="http://sapportals.com/xmlns/cm" prop_name="displayname"/>
    <property type="createdBy">USER.PRIVATE_DATASOURCE.un:LU23921</property>
    <property type="includeInRSS" prop_ns="wpc_wcm" prop_name="wpc_wcm_rss"/>
    <property type="displayNewIcon" prop_ns="wpc_wcm" prop_name="wpc_wcm_new"/>
  </properties>
  <elements>
    <element type="videotitle">TestTitle</element>
    <element type="videopath">ICT/LB_1152kbps.mp4</element>
    <element type="videowidth">500</element>
    <element type="videoheight">250</element>
  </elements>
  <relatedlinks/>
  <relatedfiles/>
</document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<elements>
   <a style="display:block;width:500px;height:250px" id="player" href="ICT/LB_1152kbps.mp4"/>
</elements>
```

Comment: How do I insert an ID in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303362/how-do-display-a-cms-collection-in-an-asp-net-page-using-an-xslt-file